# Unity 3D simple C# file send to FTP server sample script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ftp

I'm new to unity, I need a simple script to send a XML file (don't need to read contents) from "StreamingAssets" folder to our FTP server root folder with ability to change |"FTP User Name" "FTP Password" "FTP Host Name" "FTP Port"|. I have been seen some example in unity forums and unity documentation but nothing helped me. if you know simple ways please guide me thanks.

### I found this but it doesn't work.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

public class Uploader : MonoBehaviour
{
public string FTPHost     = "ftp.byethost7.com";

public string FTPUserName = "b7_18750253";

public string FTPPassword = "**********";

public string FilePath;

public void UploadFile()
{


    WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();


    Uri uri = new Uri(FTPHost + new FileInfo(FilePath).Name);

    Debug.Log (uri);


    client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(FTPUserName, FTPPassword);


    client.UploadFileAsync(uri, "STOR", FilePath);

}

void start()
   {
    FilePath = Application.dataPath+"/StreamingAssets/data.xml";

    UploadFile ();
   }

}
```

Comment: Yes that true, file is in StreamingAsset folder.

Comment: Code structure is true and Unity don't show any error, I tested with filezilla and everything works.

Comment: No and i don't know why.

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
Uri uri = new Uri(FTPHost + new FileInfo(FilePath).Name);
```

With this:

```
Uri uri = new Uri(FTPHost + "/" + new FileInfo(FilePath).Name);
```

The method `OnFileUploadCompleted` shows that the URI hasn't `"/"`.
The `Uri` constructor seemingly joins the file name with the path name without format. (Works for me in Unity 2018.2.3f1). There are other ways to format a url, I just try point the error.

Worst English ever, I know... :D

Answer (score 1):

You are simply not calling the `UploadFile()` function from anywhere. Because it is a `public` function, I assumed it is being called from another script, but since the `Debug.Log (uri);` code is not showing anything,it is likely that the function is not being called at-all. You must call it from somewhere for it to run.

For testing purposes, call it from the `Start()` function. Add the code below to your script.

```
void Start()
{
    UploadFile();
}
```

Note that you must attach the `Uploader` script to a GameObject in your scene. That GameObject must be enabled in order for your `Start()` function to be called.

**EDIT**:

Even when you do this, you will get error that says:

```
The format of the URI could not be determined: blah blah blah
```

Your `"ftp.byethost7.com";` link should be `"ftp://byethost7.com";`

Here is a complete `FTP` upload code in Unity.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

public class Uploader : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string FTPHost = "ftp://byethost7.com";
    public string FTPUserName = "b7_18750253";
    public string FTPPassword = "xxx";
    public string FilePath;

    public void UploadFile()
    {
        FilePath = Application.dataPath + "/StreamingAssets/data.xml";
        Debug.Log("Path: " + FilePath);


        WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();
        Uri uri = new Uri(FTPHost + new FileInfo(FilePath).Name);

        client.UploadProgressChanged += new UploadProgressChangedEventHandler(OnFileUploadProgressChanged);
        client.UploadFileCompleted += new UploadFileCompletedEventHandler(OnFileUploadCompleted);
        client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(FTPUserName, FTPPassword);
        client.UploadFileAsync(uri, "STOR", FilePath);
    }

    void OnFileUploadProgressChanged(object sender, UploadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.Log("Uploading Progreess: " + e.ProgressPercentage);
    }

    void OnFileUploadCompleted(object sender, UploadFileCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.Log("File Uploaded");
    }

    void Start()
    {
        UploadFile();
    }
}
```

Comment: Nothing changed. No upload. No log.

Comment: Is this address "ftp.byethost7.com" path of "htdocs" folder in FTP server?

Comment: I don't know about that but since you claim it works with FileZilla, that shouldn't be a problem at-all. The last solution. Create a temporary credential in your FTP server. That credential I will use to test your problem. Make sure to enable write/read. Zip the project with that credential, upload it somewhere and provide the link here. I will take a look at it.

Comment: Thanks. This is link of a simple unity project with above script, and FTP credentials. I hope you could solve this. I really need it.

Comment: @AliKazemi It should be `Start()` not `start()`. This is why `Debug.Log` is not even showing. Take a look at the complete upload code in my answer. I suggest you remove the current script from your gameobject. Paste the new code inside it then re-attach it to your GameObject. This should work. I was able to upload to your server with that.

Comment: Thanks for reply, Unity log file path and uploaded but nothing is in FTP folders.

Comment: @AliKazemi were you able to solve this issue? The code didn't work for me either.

Comment: The post from @Eder below does the trick if anyone faces a similar issue with this code.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.IO;

public void UploadFile2()
    {
        FilePath = Application.dataPath + "/StreamingAssets/ARITMETICA3DAZ1.txt";
        Debug.Log("Path: " + FilePath);

    Uri uri = new Uri(FTPHost + "/" + new FileInfo(FilePath).Name);
    FtpState state = new FtpState();
    FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential (FTPUserName,FTPPassword);

    state.Request = request;
    state.FileName = FilePath;

    request.BeginGetRequestStream(
        //new AsyncCallback (EndGetStreamCallback), 
        new AsyncCallback (EndGetStreamCallback), 
        state
    );




    public class FtpState
    {
        private ManualResetEvent wait;
        private FtpWebRequest request;
        private string fileName;
        private Exception operationException = null;
        string status;

        public FtpState()
        {
            wait = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        }

        public ManualResetEvent OperationComplete
        {
            get {return wait;}
        }

        public FtpWebRequest Request
        {
            get {return request;}
            set {request = value;}
        }

        public string FileName
        {
            get {return fileName;}
            set {fileName = value;}
        }
        public Exception OperationException
        {
            get {return operationException;}
            set {operationException = value;}
        }
        public string StatusDescription
        {
            get {return status;}
            set {status = value;}
        }
    }
    public class AsynchronousFtpUpLoader
    {  
        // Command line arguments are two strings:
        // 1. The url that is the name of the file being uploaded to the server.
        // 2. The name of the file on the local machine.
        //
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Create a Uri instance with the specified URI string.
            // If the URI is not correctly formed, the Uri constructor
            // will throw an exception.
            ManualResetEvent waitObject;

            Uri target = new Uri (args[0]);
            string fileName = args[1];
            FtpState state = new FtpState();
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(target);
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

            // This example uses anonymous logon.
            // The request is anonymous by default; the credential does not have to be specified. 
            // The example specifies the credential only to
            // control how actions are logged on the server.

            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential ("anonymous","janeDoe@contoso.com");

            // Store the request in the object that we pass into the
            // asynchronous operations.
            state.Request = request;
            state.FileName = fileName;

            // Get the event to wait on.
            waitObject = state.OperationComplete;

            // Asynchronously get the stream for the file contents.
            request.BeginGetRequestStream(
                new AsyncCallback (EndGetStreamCallback), 
                state
            );

            // Block the current thread until all operations are complete.
            waitObject.WaitOne();

            // The operations either completed or threw an exception.
            if (state.OperationException != null)
            {
                throw state.OperationException;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The operation completed - {0}", state.StatusDescription);
            }
        }
        private static void EndGetStreamCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            FtpState state = (FtpState) ar.AsyncState;

            Stream requestStream = null;
            // End the asynchronous call to get the request stream.
            try
            {
                requestStream = state.Request.EndGetRequestStream(ar);
                // Copy the file contents to the request stream.
                const int bufferLength = 2048;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferLength];
                int count = 0;
                int readBytes = 0;
                FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(state.FileName);
                do
                {
                    readBytes = stream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                    requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, readBytes);
                    count += readBytes;
                }
                while (readBytes != 0);
                Console.WriteLine ("Writing {0} bytes to the stream.", count);
                // IMPORTANT: Close the request stream before sending the request.
                requestStream.Close();
                // Asynchronously get the response to the upload request.
                state.Request.BeginGetResponse(
                    new AsyncCallback (EndGetResponseCallback), 
                    state
                );
            } 
            // Return exceptions to the main application thread.
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Could not get the request stream.");
                state.OperationException = e;
                state.OperationComplete.Set();
                return;
            }

        }

        // The EndGetResponseCallback method  
        // completes a call to BeginGetResponse.
        private static void EndGetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            FtpState state = (FtpState) ar.AsyncState;
            FtpWebResponse response = null;
            try 
            {
                response = (FtpWebResponse) state.Request.EndGetResponse(ar);
                response.Close();
                state.StatusDescription = response.StatusDescription;
                // Signal the main application thread that 
                // the operation is complete.
                state.OperationComplete.Set();
            }
            // Return exceptions to the main application thread.
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine ("Error getting response.");
                state.OperationException = e;
                state.OperationComplete.Set();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do not add a code only answer, you need to give your code some context and explain why it solves the OP's problem, so that the OP and future Googlers can understand your answer.